# Loop through span items in selenium python

Tags: python, html, loops, selenium, object

I'm trying to click on each item in a span using Selenium.  Is it possible to specify this in a for loop and how could I do this?

This is how I currently click on the first span item:

```
 _open_actieve_polis = {"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "td:nth-child(2)"}

self._click(self._open_actieve_polis)
```

in the base page this is how i implemented the _click method.

```
def _find(self, locator):
    return self.driver.find_element(locator["by"], locator["value"])

 def _click(self, locator):
        self._find(locator).click()
```

these are the other span items I want to click:

```
tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > span > a
tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > span > a
tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > span > a
tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(2) > span > a
tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2) > span > a
```

This is what I tried after applying feedback:

This in a method:

```
for link in self._open_actieve_polis:
        self._click_all(link)
        self.driver.back()
```

I declared the locator in an attribute:

```
_open_actieve_polis = ({"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "td:nth-child(2)"})
```

the following in base page:

```
 def _find_all(self, locator):
        return self.driver.find_elements(locator["by"], locator["value"])

    def _click_all(self, locator):
        self._find_all(locator).click()
```

is currently resulting in:

```
     line 18, in _find_all
    return self.driver.find_elements(locator["by"], locator["value"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Show your implementation of `_click()` method

Comment: i edited the original post.

Comment: Can you please share more html code for link

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement another method. Something like

```
def _find_all(self, locator):
    return self.driver.find_elements(locator["by"], locator["value"])
```

that intend to return you *list of elements* instead of *single element*...

With this method you can try to get list of links

```
self.links = self._find_all({"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > span > a"})
```

and loop through it with this

```
for link in self.links:
    link.click()
```

or add new method to click each element in list:

```
def _click_all(self, locator):
    [element.click() for element in self._find_all(locator)]
```

and call it as

```
self._click_all({"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > span > a"})
```

Note that to get list of links for each table row you should remove `tr` index from you selector:

```
tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)  -->  tr > td:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: I feel like I'm almost there But I'm receiving a type error. I edited my original post. Am I interpreting wrongly?

Comment: It seem that you're trying to pass `locator` variable as string, but not dictionary and so `locator["by"]` gives you `TypeError`

Comment: now i'm getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'. my head is spinning been looking at it all day.

Comment: On which line you got it?

Comment: How your `locator` looks like? Is it string or dict?

Comment: This is my locator:

    _open_actieve_polis = ({"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "td:nth-child(2)"})

Comment: This is tuple that contains one dict... Try `_open_actieve_polis = {"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "td:nth-child(2)"}`

Comment: Same error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" :-(

Comment: oh... Just noticed... You did `for link in self._open_actieve_polis: self._click_all(link)`... Don't do that :) Just do `self._click_all({"by": By.CSS_SELECTOR, "value": "tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > span > a"})` without loops...

Comment: line 24, in _click_all
    self._find_all(locator).click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: No. Why did you do it in that way?! :) Just pass `locator` as dictionary to `self._click_all(__put_locator_here__)`. Don't add `_find_all()`, don't add `click()`!!!

Comment: that's what I did. the error from line 24 is coming from the bass page. I'm calling self._click_all(locator) in a page object exactly like you suggested.

Comment: I've tried similar code from my side and everything works fine... You probably do something wrong. Can you post new ticket with your exact code and current output?

Comment: I appreciate your assitance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712495/loop-through-span-elements-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's `find_elements()` method (as well as its `find_elements_by_*()` methods, all return a simple list of elements. Lists don't have a `click()` method.

Instead, you'll need to iterate over the elements, clicking each one in turn.

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS, "...")
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

---

Note: Selenium has a `find_elements_by_css_selector()` method that you can use instead of `find_elements()`:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("...")
```